# The link is not working?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a button in template Django

```
<li><a href=""><button type="submit" class="submitLink" value="duplicate" name="duplicate">Duplicate</button></a></li>
```

if i click this button the form will submit 
`<form id="my_form" method="post" action=".">{% csrf_token %}` , here it is working fine when i click the name in Duplicate but else in button it will not work, please help me , any other method is there please help me out
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<li><button type="submit" class="submitLink" value="duplicate" name="duplicate">Duplicate</button></li>
```

i.e. remove  tag

or you can try this too:

```
<li><input type="submit" class="submitLink" value="duplicate" name="duplicate"></li>
```